# how does bitcoin prevent double-spending?

Tags: python, security, pseudocode, bitcoin

can someone help me create a Pseudocode that shows how bitcoin prevents double-spending?
here is my code (with some help of https://www.sofi.com/) :

```
This program is to prevent double-spending:

Person A and Person B go to a store with only one collective BTC to spend.
Person A buys a TV costing exactly 1 BTC.
Person B buys a motorcycle that also costs exactly 1 BTC.
blockchain = []
pool_of_unconfirmed_transactions = []

Both transactions go into a pool of unconfirmed transactions:
pool_of_unconfirmed_transactions.append(person A buys)
pool_of_unconfirmed_transactions.append(person B buys)

only the first transaction gets confirmations
and is verified by miners in the next block.
If person A buys == first buyer:
    person A's transaction == valid
    blockchain.append(person A's transaction)
    del mem_pool[person B's transaction]
else:
    person B's transaction == valid
    del mem_pool[person A's transaction]

Whichever transaction gets the maximum number of network confirmations
(typically a minimum of six) will be included in the blockchain,
 while others are discarded.
Once confirmations and transactions are put on the blockchain
 they are time-stamped, rendering them irreversible and impossible to alter.
```

Is it ok?
any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin prevents double-spending by not producing a block that spends UTXO that has been spent earlier by another block. Memory pool or unconfirmed transactions have nothing to do with it.

A Bitcoin block that contains a double-spend would not be a valid block and thus all Bitcoin nodes in the world would reject it. This is also why it is called "public ledger" - Bitcoin blockchain is the account book (ledger) of all balances of the whole system.

Thus if there are two competing transactions miners will decide which is spent and which is rejected.

Comment: can you write it in a Pseudocode? please❤

Comment: It is better you read and study the Bitcoind source code yourself.